# Is migration from docker to vm possible?

Tags: virtual-machine, containers, docker

How to migrate from docker container to virtual machine ? Can somebody give links if any ?

Comment: what do you mean & what have you tried?

Comment: i need to move an application running in docker container say apache server to another virtual machine. How to achieve this ?

Comment: Off topic. Should be serverfault.com question.

Comment: I just gave an example...

Answer (score 0):

```
vagrant up
sudo apt-get install lxc-docker
docker import ...
```

I'm being serious here. This is the whole fun of Docker!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean migrating the services running in docker container to a VM, you could use the Dockerfile as an installation script base.